# What would users expect from tapping 'menu' during game play?

Tags: user-expectation

This question relates to a trivia game app. From the main menu users can choose how many questions they want to be asked, the choices being 10, 25, 50 and so on.

Once they make a choice they're taken to the Question screen and start to answer questions. In addition to also showing your score and the number of questions asked, there is also a 'reset' option and 'menu' option.

**My question is this:**

By tapping on 'menu' would users be expecting to be taken to the main menu screen and:

1. still have their current score and question tally remain intact so they can continue the game later, or
2. abandon their current game (i.e. the score and question tally are reset to zero), or
3. something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By tapping on 'menu' would users be expecting to be taken to the main
>   menu screen and:

When a user click on a `menu` icon while the game is in progress, I would normally show a confirmation box and give him three options

1)   **Pause Game**

2)   **Quit Game** to Menu

3)   **Cancel**, Back to Game

Unless user wants to stop the game, I wouldn't just quit the game on his behalf.

**BUT**

If this game is **not one of those** which

- Requires **continued observation and actions** from the user like a racing game,
- and Has continous movements of objects and would always require to be played from beginning.

**THEN**

You should just **save the state of the game as is** and won't bother asking the user any questions.  Game should start from the same position where it was left of.

Examples of such games would be

- Solitaire
- Chess
- **Quiz** (unless there is a mandatory time limit and quiz cannot be played again).